# An issue with "[checked]= true" in angular2

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have kind of managing orders within restaurants `angular2` application. So I have this code :

```
 <md-radio-group>
   <span *ngFor="let extIng of item.extra_ingredients;">
      <md-radio-button *ngIf="extIng.default === false" [value]="extIng" (click)="toggleNotMultipExtraConfig(extIng)">
        <span>{{extIng.name}}</span>
      </md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button *ngIf="extIng.default === true"  [value]="extIng" (click)="toggleNotMultipExtraConfig(extIng)" [checked]=true> 
        <span>{{extIng.name}}</span>
      </md-radio-button>
   </span>
 </md-radio-group>
```

And this TS part:

```
@Input() item: Item;
public oneChoiceConfig:          any[]= [];

//....

toggleNotMultipExtraConfig(extra: any): void {

  this.oneChoiceConfig.push(extra);

}
```

which both generate this :
[image]
My problem is that when adding the `[checked]=true` parameter so that I'll get some default checked item's toppings, but once submitting the order, I got nothing pushed in `oneChoiceConfig` , so I want a trick that helps me to **push** **that default checked extra** to `oneChoiceConfig` (as done after firing the method `toggleNotMultipExtraConfig()` ) and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a workaround like this in your TS file:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {

  this.item.extra_ingredients.forEach((value, key) {
    if (value.default === true) {
      this.oneChoiceConfig.push(v);
    }
  })
}
```

And do not forget to **import** and **implement** `AfterContentInit`.

Answer (score 1):

One of possible solution is to add this topping inside ngOnInit hook like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.item.extra_ingredients
      .filter(extra => extra.default)
      .map(extra => this.oneChoiceConfig.push(extra);

}
```

One more thing I can suggest is simplifying html template. Instead of:

```
  <md-radio-button *ngIf="extIng.default === false" [value]="extIng" (click)="toggleNotMultipExtraConfig(extIng)">
    <span>{{extIng.name}}</span>
  </md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button *ngIf="extIng.default === true"  [value]="extIng" (click)="toggleNotMultipExtraConfig(extIng)" [checked]=true> 
    <span>{{extIng.name}}</span>
  </md-radio-button>
```

You can use this:

```
 <md-radio-button [value]="extIng" (click)="toggleNotMultipExtraConfig(extIng)" [checked]="extIng.default">
    <span>{{extIng.name}}</span>
  </md-radio-button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot , I think it is a similar answer to the checked one , but a bit later .. I've upvoted!